# Determine the formula of a function by known points

Tags: functions

The points of the function graph are known. Need to find function formula.

All known points:

A(2, 70); 
B(3, 66.5); 
C(4, 63.0); 
D(5, 59.5); 
E(6, 56.0); 
F(7, 52.5); 
G(8, 49.0); 
H(9, 45.5); 
I(10, 42.0); 
J(11, 38.5); 
K(12, 35.0); 
L(13, 31.5); 
M(14, 28.0); 
N(15, 24.5); 
O(16, 21.0); 
P(17, 17.5); 
Q(18, 14.0); 
R(19, 10.5); 
S(20, 7.0);

Start from A (2, 70) to finish at S (20, 7).
Probably is it "y = kx + b", but I'm not sure.
X always increases by 1, and Y always decreases by 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = mx +b$ is an equation of a line with slope $m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$, where $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are any two points.

So let's use points A and E. The slope is then $$\frac{56-70}{6-2}=\frac{-14}{4}= -3.5$$

Then we have $y = -3.5x + b$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: and what's about 'b'? =)

Comment: Use (substitute) the coordinates of any point $(x,y)$ into that equation and you will have something like $$49 = -3.5*(8) + b$$ then solve for *b*

Comment: thank you.....!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it's a straight line of the form
$$
f(x) = kx+b
$$
for some $k,b \in \mathbb{R}$. You can take any two points and solve for the coefficients $a$ and $b$, and you're done. Apparently you already found the value of $k$ ...

Comment: ye, I know it.

But when I calculate 'a' and 'b' values, that I got zero :d

Comment: How did you calculate them?

Comment: substituted the x and y values ​​of the start and end points in the formula

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more about the function (is it a polynomial, is it monotonic, etc.) because otherwise there are infinitely many functions that pass those points and there is no single answer to your question. Effectively, any graph you draw that connects the points will be a function provided no $x$ value corresponds to two $y$ values.

Knowing that a function is linear across a range of sampled points doesn't guarantee that it is necessarily linear in-between those points. For instance, it could be curved, oscillating, or even discontinuous between the sample points.

See [Wikipedia: Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) for more information. The method that you should use will depend on the assumptions you can make and what you are trying to accomplish.

If you *can* make the assumption that it is a straight line, it suffices to find the slope between two points, $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$, and then find the $y$-intercept, $c$, by substituting some known values into $y=mx+c$.

Comment: TMI $$$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 It's not TMI though. The OP doesn't categorically know that the function is a line.

Comment: "The method that you should use will depend on the assumptions you can make and what you are trying to accomplish." - if we apply that to the process of asking and answering questions here on MSE, then it should be clear that this question wasn't found in the "technically correct" section on functions, but likely on determining the equation of a line from known points. Sure, this answer is correct, but I don't find it helpful.